# No such property: mvn for class

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I created a Groovy script for Jenkins, where I run checks on my Projects with Maven:

```
node {
    stage ('DEV'){
        git 'samplegitadress'
        def mvnHome = tool 'M3'
        mvn -f /opt/maven
        sh 'mvn -B validate'
}
}
```

But I get following Error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: mvn for class: groovy.lang.Binding
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mvn -f /opt/maven` should be called within `sh`. Just as the line below it.